# The operator class 'concurrency:cross_validation' is unknown. Possibly you must install a plugin for operators of group 'concurrency'

Tags: java, rapidminer

I am working on RapidMiner and trying to integrate it with Java code. But I am getting this error for cross validation operator which is used in RapidMiner process.

I searched for it, and I found that certain plugin installation can solve the issue. Is anyone can help me in this issue, with plugin name or any other solution.

Please find the screenshot for Java code and console log for your reference:
[Java Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzyEW.png)    [Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYgIm.png)

Comment: Show us your file I mean what is the input maybe there is some issue about that?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, the RapidMiner process you try to execute includes the new Cross-Validation Operator, that was released with version 7.3 (see the release notes: http://docs.rapidminer.com/studio/releases/7.3/).

The linked RapidMiner version with which you are trying to execute the process is probably an older one. So I would recommend to use a newer version (as it also offers parallel execution of the Cross Validation) or change the RapidMiner process to use the older X-Validation Operator.